# Can't ssh using dynamically generated host

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

I have a shell script that runs a python script to return an AWS IP and then is supposed to ssh into that IP. Simple:

```
DNS=$(python ssh_into_master.py)
ssh $DNS
```

It runs the command as it's supposed to, but the connection is refused.

```
> ssh -i /path/to/key.pem.txt ec2-user@the.ip.i.returned
> ssh: connect to host the.ip.i.returned port 22: Connection refused
```

But if I just type in the exact same command manually, the connection is accepted. Why is the connection refused when the argument to the ssh command is dynamically generated? I thought maybe it was a permissions issue with the key file, but the shell script is run by the same user who created the key, so shouldn't it have the same permissions?

EDIT:

Here is a sanitized version of the python script.

```
# This script gets the public dns for the master ec2 instance in an auto-scaling group

import boto3
import sys
import time

autoscaling = boto3.client('autoscaling')
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def get_dns(instance_id):

    # IF THE INSTANCE IS NOT YET CREATED, WAIT 10s AND TRY AGAIN

    status = ec2.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    if len(status['InstanceStatuses']) == 0:
        time.sleep(10)
        get_dns(instance_id)
        return

    status = status['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']['Name']

    # IF THE INSTANCE IS PENDING BUT NOT YET RUNNING, WAIT 15s AND TRY AGAIN

    if status != 'running':
        time.sleep(15)
        get_dns(instance_id)
        return

    dns = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
    dns = dns['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['PublicDnsName']
    dns = dns.split('.compute')[0].replace('-', '.')[4:]

    print ' -i /path/to/key.pem.txt' \
          ' ec2-user@%s' % dns

def main():
    groups_list = autoscaling.describe_auto_scaling_groups()['AutoScalingGroups']
    # find the master group
    for group in groups_list:
        if group['LaunchConfigurationName'] == 'master':
            if not group['Instances']:
                # the group hasn't been launched yet, so wait 5 seconds
                time.sleep(5)
                main()
            else:
                instance_id = group['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
                get_dns(instance_id)


main()
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full shell script, the source (sanitized, if need be) of the python script, and example output.

Comment: Perhaps you should copy the whole output and try to run that string instead of typing it out yourself. It can be a simple formatting mistake that cause this.

Comment: @mootmoot - when I copy and paste the output, I get the connection refused. But I see no difference in the output and what I type.

Comment: You can try to assign the output to a variable call output , then use print repr(output)  , this should show some hidden character. Btw, from the code, where is the publicDNS derive from?  It is undeclared.

Comment: @mootmoot - publicDNS was a typo left over from when I was sanitizing the code. I fixed that now. I don't see any hidden character when I try printing repr(output). For now, I've implemented a workaround by assigning an elastic IP to the instance and hardcoding that into the shell script. But I am still mystified by why the original won't work.

Comment: You seem to be parsing the public IP from the public DNS name: `dns = dns.split('.compute')[0].replace('-', '.')[4:]`? Can you not just do `ssh ec2-user@<PublicDnsName>`?

Comment: @Jukka - yes, the reason I tried parsing the public IP from the PublicDnsName is because doing `ssh ec2-user@<PublicDnsName>` wasn't working. But it didn't help.

Comment: I think you aren't waiting long enough. The instance may be running, but ssh daemon doesn't start for some seconds after that.

Comment: @MichaelHampton : Hopefully this is the case. Otherwise if the copy and paste doesn't work after the typing, it means the parse string  contains something that ssh doesn't recognise.   Normally I use "string".format() to pass argument for string (together with strip), which reduce some surprises.